# "Athena.InvalidRequestException" in Step function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to read the query string from input but step function gives - "Athena.InvalidRequestException"

```
{
  "StartAt": "CallFunction",
  "States": {
    "CallFunction": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:12345:function:readFile",
      "ResultPath": "$.query",
      "Next": "Start an Athena query"
    },
    "Start an Athena query": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueryString": "$.query",
        "WorkGroup": "primary",
        "ResultConfiguration": {
          "OutputLocation": "s3://test_athena/test1"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Intput of Start an Athena query state:

```
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here",
  "query": "\"SELECT *   FROM test1   LIMIT 10;  \""
}
```

Getting the below error on Start an Athena query state :

```
{
  "resourceType": "athena",
  "resource": "startQueryExecution.sync",
  "error": "Athena.InvalidRequestException",
  "cause": "line 1:1: mismatched input '$'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CALL', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT', 'PREPARE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'UNLOAD', 'UPDATE', 'USE', <query> (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 2a99f6eb-b853-407f-b229-d309a4ca3f5c; Proxy: null)"
}
```

I'm new to AWS. Can someone help me out in this how to pass query object in QueryString parameter of Athena ?

Comment: you should remove the explicit double quotes from the query string, so it looks like `"query" : "select..."`

Comment: I tried this as well by passing query inside input but same error. 
` { "Comment": "Insert your JSON here", 
"test1": "SELECT * FROM test1 LIMIT 10;",
 "query": "\"SELECT * FROM test1 LIMIT 10; \"" } 
` and in step function updated it like this - 
` "QueryString": "$.test1", `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ".$" annotation in your QueryString key:

```
"QueryString.$": "$.query",
```

> [...] The values of [your Parameter fields] can either be static values that you include in your state machine definition, or selected from either the input or the context object with a path. For key-value pairs where the value is selected using a path, the key name must end in .$.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters

Also, you should add the following fields in your second state, to be explicit there:

```
"Type": "Task",
"End": true
```